# property function throws exception

Tags: c#, winforms, properties

I have a public property exposing a class manager (ViewManager) which manages what views are available to which users.  This property (and several others) call a function called PopulateCollections() and then returns the private field _Views.

```
private bool _CollectionsPopulated = false;
public ViewManager Views { get { PopulateCollections(); return _Views;}}
void PopulateCollections()
{
    if (_CollectionsPopulated) return;
    _CollectionsPopulated = true;
    foreach (ClassTable item in ClassessTables)
    {
        item.ReflectMe();
    }
}
```

ClassTable is another class that stores the structure of a class within a database table. 
The function ReflectMe() calls upon each class item to acquire each classes' attrbiutes.

All this code works great.
My problem is a timing one.

When the code runs, 99% of the time I have no issues.  But for that 1%, the function PopulateCollections() takes too long and it causes an exception.

When parsing thru each available Model (each with their own group of ClassesTables), I get to this point where I'm looking at the Views...

```
If  ((ThisModel != null) && (ThisModel.Views != null))
{
    //Code here
}
```

When it gets to the "ThisModel.Views" which triggers PopulateCollections for the first time, when I hover over ThisModel.Views, I get the following:

> "'ThisModel.Views' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'"

However, after a second longer, when I hover over it again, I get the actual values that I'm expecting.  This tells me the PopulateCollections() code is still reflecting each class because when I run it without debugging, the exception thrown is

> "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute."

So...How do I make the code wait explicitly until this method is done?

Comment: I suspect `ReflectMe` adds or removes an element from collection. Is it?

Comment: Are you using multiple threads? What's the stack trace?

Comment: Sriram: Yes and no.  The ClassesTable items would remain constant, but the properties of these items is what would change.

Comment: SLaks: It is a multi-threaded application, but at this point in the code it's running on a single thread (Main Thread).  There are up to 25+ Worker Threads but I didn't create them to do anything.  The RelfectMe() should run and nothing else should happen till it does.  Because it's running WHILE I hover over the property, I get the InvalidOperationException which I understand.  What I dodn't get is why I'm getting the Collection was modified exception error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution came from left field...the CLASS being populated was the issue.  The code, however didn't tell me this, afterwards, the code as it was originally worked without a hitch.

Answer (score 1):

What I think is deceiving is that your `_CollectionsPopulated` flag does not really indicate that the collection is fully populated. When you call the `Views` property twice, in quick succession, the second time it will return even though the collection is still being created.

I propose adding another flag which tracks the state of the collection.  If the collection is in the middle of being filled in, don't try to repopulate it, but instead return `null`.

```
private bool _collectionsPopulating = false;
private bool _CollectionsPopulated = false;
public ViewManager Views 
{ 
     get 
     { 
         if (_collectionsPopulating) return null;
         PopulateCollections(); 
         return _collectionsPopulat_Views;
     }
}

void PopulateCollections()
{
    if (_CollectionsPopulated) return;
    _collectionsPopulating = true;
    foreach (ClassTable item in ClassessTables)
    {
        item.ReflectMe();
    }
    _CollectionsPopulated = true;
    _collectionsPopulating = false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  This however did not do the trick because now it's returrning null items, which is not good either.

Comment: Stupid enter key! I see what you're doing and it does make more sense to keep tabs on both completed and completing functions.  There has to be some sort of multithreaded process going on because if it WAS single-threaded, this error wouldn't occur...I'll have to look deeper as to what's going on...